# How come this container expands to full width?

Tags: css

Was taking a look at this theme:

http://themes.3rdwavemedia.com/demo/devaid/

How does this `.container` expand to the full width of the page? When I want to make a container like that I need to do `.container-fluid` and set padding to 0.

Comment: please check its section which is full width not container

Answer (score 1):

It's not. It's a bog-standard Bootstrap non-fluid `.container`. The `<section>` tag it's within has the background styling.

[image]

Right-click, "Inspect Element". It'll serve you well in the future.